# Is there a way to know when a facebook embed is done loading?

Tags: javascript, facebook, embed, oembed

Just trying to figure out if there's some type of javascript I can run that tells me exactly when the html is done being loaded. We use `iframely` to embed social media posts. The result is something like this

```
<div data-oembed-url="https://www.facebook.com/newser/posts/10158977245120245">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/newser/posts/10158977245120245" data-iframely-url="https://cdn.iframe.ly/api/iframe?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnewser%2Fposts%2F10158977245120245&amp;key=7b9a9feadb0deb20b694e1d595fdccee">Newser</a>
    <script async="" src="https://cdn.iframe.ly/embed.js" charset="utf-8"><script>
</div>
```

I just want to know when this is actually done getting the html and rendering it.

Comment: if iframely doesn't provide a callback, you can set load handlers on the dynamic iframes. these will appear in the almost-forgotten _window.frames_

Comment: That's interesting, do you happen to have an example?

Comment: i don't, but it's just a regular `load` event that the iframe tag fires when the doc loads. if the tag were not dynamically added, a plain `<iframe onload=alert(123) src=...` would work

Comment: That would assume there's an iframe. We don't load an iframe, we use oembed to generate HTML that later gets changed. I don't have access to the HTML element iframe, in my db its just divs and a script tag that changed said div's to the embed code.

Comment: Can you not use CSS3 to create an animation effect based on the load event if its dynamic then you could i think incorporate it